# Adding all the elements from an enum into an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, enums

Is there a way to iterate through all the elements of an enum to add them into a LinkedList?

The example that I'm trying to do: I'm making a deck of cards. I have 2 enums: rank and value. Using a nested for loop, I want to have every card of the deck added into the ArrayList, using the 2 enums.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want every permutation of the two enums?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the .values() static function of the enum class.

You could use:

```
for(Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
  for (Value val : Value.values()) {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
enum Rank { ... }

enum Suit { ... }

class Card {
    Rank rank;
    Suit suit;

    Card(Rank r, Suit s) { rank = r; suit = s; }
}
```

Then later..

```
List<Card> all() {
    List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Rank r : Rank.values()) {
        for (Suit s : Suit.values()) {
            cards.add(new Card(r, s));
        }
    }

    return cards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you'll need to do is to create a `Card` class.

Once you have that, loop through each element of the first enum (use `.values()` to get each element), and for each element, loop through each element of the second enum.  In that second loop, create a new `Card` with those values.

Answer (score 1):

Enums have the `values()` method, which returns an array of the instances.

Use two nested foreach loops:

```
List<Card> deck = new LinkedList<>();
for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
    for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
        deck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
for(Rank r : Rank.values()){
    for(Value v : Value.values()) {
        // new Car(r, v);
    }
}
```

This assumes you have a Card class, with a constructor that takes each enum as a parameter.  You'd also need a list or other collection to hold the cards.